# Issues when declaring an XML namespace inside a SQL Server table-valued function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xpath

I am having trouble including an XML namespace in the following table-valued function. I need this namespace in order to perform an xpath join. The issue seems to be my use of the **WITH** method, but this syntax is required when I execute the query in straight SQL.

The exact error reads:

> "Incorrect syntax near 'default'. Expected ID or QUOTED_ID."

Does anyone know the exact syntax for including an XML namespace in this T-SQL table-valued function body? Here is the T-SQL code:

USE [Context]
    GO

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStuff]()
RETURNS @X TABLE(
  DisplayName NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
  StandardCode NVARCHAR(250) NULL
)
--WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS      
BEGIN

DECLARE @MyTempTable  TABLE ( 
  DisplayName NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
  StandardCode NVARCHAR(250) NULL
);

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://www.mynamespace.org/someSchema')

INSERT INTO @MyTempTable (DisplayName, StandardCode)
    SELECT Distinct OI.DisplayName, OI.StandardCode
    FROM db..Actor B
    JOIN db..Part DP ON B.Id = DP.Id
    JOIN db..Intent OI ON OI.StandardCode = DP.XML.value('(/US/California/Orange/LA/Pizza)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    JOIN db..Status PS ON B.Id = PS.Id
    WHERE PS.StandardCode in ('Happy','Employed')
    AND OI.Active = 1
    ORDER BY OI.DisplayName

  RETURN;

  END
```

Comment: I updated the question to give background on the error I am seeing. thx!

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear:  exactly what error message are you getting?

Comment: I added the exact error I am seeing to the question

Comment: Why are you declaring another table instead of inserting into @X?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that is a good point. If you answer the question I will mark it as the answer! As a  follow up: do you know why SQL Management Studio believes ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default '...') is a syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this solves the syntax error, but you are creating a second table variable for nothing. This:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStuff]()
RETURNS @X TABLE(
  DisplayName NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
  StandardCode NVARCHAR(250) NULL
)
--WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS      
BEGIN

DECLARE @MyTempTable  TABLE ( 
  DisplayName NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
  StandardCode NVARCHAR(250) NULL
);

;WITH ... INSERT @MyTempTable ...
```

Should be:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStuff]()
RETURNS @X TABLE(
  DisplayName NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
  StandardCode NVARCHAR(250) NULL
)
--WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS      
BEGIN

;WITH ... INSERT @X ...
```

Comment: this does resolve the issue I am having. SQL Management Studio highlights  ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default '...') as a syntax error and that was misleading me when trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: Management Studio's IntelliSense is far from perfect. It's useful, but sometimes you have to ignore its parsing quirks and focus on runtime errors.